# Excel to JSON response

Tags: json, web-services, api, json.net

I have an Excel Spread Sheet that I would like to convert to a JSON response API. Are there any code examples?  I am familiar with PHP, .Net, Java, JavaScript, etc. so any language will work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP "fopen" and "fgetcsv" if you save your excel sheet as a csv file. Could also work with a xlsx file - if not, save as csv. After processing the PHP you can use Javascript with json_encode to fill the values inside an array. See example:

```
<?php  
        if (($handle = fopen("your file", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
            $i = 0;
            while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) { 
                for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) { 
                    $dataarray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; ");
                }
                $i++;
            } 
            fclose($handle); 
        }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data= <?php echo json_encode($dataarray); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns data that looks like this:[["LastName","FirstName","Email","Correct","CorrectLate","Incorrect","IncorrectUnassigned"],["Chandler","Brandon","test@test.com","0","0","3","0"],["Cooper","Justin","test@test.com","8","0","0","0"],

Comment: How would you like to have your data?